# Method overloading or overriding?

Tags: java, oop

We have a Parent and child class, which has method with the same name but argument are as primitive and wrapper. Could someone please explain the reason whether this would be referred as Method Overriding and Method overloading. Running this program would invoke Parent method - which would be overriding and not overloading, looking for explanations.

```
class Parent {
    public void takeValue(int a) {
        System.out.println("take value method from parent is invoked");
    }
}

class Child extends Parent {
    public void takeValue(Integer a) {
        System.out.println("take value method from child is invoked");

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Parent p = new Child();
        p.takeValue(new Integer(51));
    }
}
```

Comment: kinda overloading: classical definition of overloading is providing a method with the same name but different signature in *the same* class. Here you're doing it in an inherited class.

Answer (score 3):

The method is overloaded.

> Running this program would invoke Parent method - which would be overriding and not overloading

Yes. You're calling `takeValue` on a `Parent` variable, which means that the compiler will look for a signature match on the `Parent` class. The overload is not even visible here (signatures are matched based on static types, i.e., java finds the method based on the declared data type of the variable on which the method is called, not with the data type of the object assigned to the variable, which would be a runtime thing).

And because `public void takeValue(Integer a)` is not considered by the compiler when checking the method invocation, `p.takeValue(new Integer(51));` is linked to `Parent.takeValue(int)` by virtue of autoboxing (it would have matched the other method if both of them were visible - or declared in the `Parent` class in this example).

Comment: can you please elaborate a bit or refer an article around signatures are matched based on static types

Comment: @greenHorn don't know whether the line I added explains it... but 'static' in that case means based on information available at compile time. Java validates method invocations based on the data type of the variable on which the method is called, in addition to parameters that are passed. In other words, the compiler doesn't know whether the instance is a Child object. If you declared `p` with `Child p = new Child();`, the compiler would pick the right overload, and that would be because it can now see both method overloads (child + inherited), whereas `Parent` would only show the parent's

Answer (score 2):

This is overloading. You have same name but type of input parameters are different.

To confirm that, you will get an error when you try to attach the `@Override` annotation.

`Integer` and `int` are different types.